# how to control the Animation with touchesMoved or other

Tags: uiimageview

i have some pictures, they will show one by one when my finger moved on the screen of ipad,if my finger stoped,the stop at once,i use the following code in touchesMoved function

```
if (j>1199) {
        j=1000;
    }
    else {
         NSString *imgPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j] ofType:@"png"];
         show360img.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
        j;
    }
```

but it doesn't work well,so how can i control this Animation?thanks a lot

Comment: @sergio it does not run smoothly

Answer (score 0):

j is not been incremented.
increment j and try the code

```
if (j>1199) {
    j=1000;
}
else {
     NSString *imgPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j] ofType:@"png"];
     show360img.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
   j++;
}
```